# Why do my UITableViewCells turn grey when I tap on them?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I tap on the cells of my table view, they darken to a grey color, and don't turn back to white until I tap on a different cell. Is there some sort of Boolean I have to set for it to not do that?

Here's a screenshot explaining my problem:

[image]

Links to other websites would be helpful, if it would mean a more detailed description. (Unless it's a super simple fix, then the right code or steps-to-take would be easier than a link.)

Comment: So, when you press on a cell, you just want the check mark and not the gray selection?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of UITableView.

You must call `deselectRowAtIndexPath` inside of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` inside your UITableViewController class.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Check out the iOS Documentation for more information.

[UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/)
[UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This did exactly what I wanted. Thanks, Qasim!

Comment: Consider @Anthony Dito's answer. This avoids a row flashing grey when tapped.

Comment: correct solution is : **cell.selectionStyle = .none** in cellForRowAt method

Answer (score 31):

**Swift 3**

**Option 1: (Which I always use)**

To give it fade out animation after selected with gray you can do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

**Option 2:**

To remove the highlight effect completely you can add this line to your `cellForRowAt` :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = .....
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Your option 2 helped me resolved my problem of flashing gray background effect before the color I set. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user30646 Happy that it helped you :)

Answer (score 12):

You can do this a couple ways...

1. `tableView.allowsSelection = false`
2. You can set the tableView in xCode Storyboard to not have any selection under the fourth tab.
3. Or, you can do this on the cell `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None`

What you want is ultimately going to be about what behavior you are going after. Just do a little experimenting.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

In a custom cell add this:

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    selectionStyle = .none
}
```

This ensures you won't even see the gray when the cell is tapped. This code in the UITableViewDelegate only deselects when tapped.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Simply click on the cell and go to attributes inspector you will find Selection Style , select none.

Answer (score 1):

You   can change style by:

```
 [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.1

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard or xib,
In the Tableview cell,
you can select selection to "none",
in the atributes inspector

[image]